# upload progress for video upload from node to s3

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an angular app where a user can upload a video, user can now select a file and it will upload it to my node server and then to aws S3.

```
router.post('/file-upload', upload.single('file'), async (req, res) => {

  const { path,name,teamid } = req.body;

  const params = {
    Bucket: process.env.AWS_BUCKET_PATH,
    Key: path,
    Body: fs.createReadStream(req.file.path),
    ACL: 'public-read',
  };

  try{
    await s3Client.putObject(params);

    //log the total % and then send the info back to my front end to display to the user

    console.log('uploaded');
          db.collection("teams").doc(teamid).collection('Film').doc(name).set(
            {
              link: process.env.AWS_CLOUDFRONT_LEAD+params.Key,
              title: name
            })
  }catch{}
  res.send({});

});
```

I would like to have a progress % as well as a total storage used at the destination folder.